# Is an operator A still a contraction if $\rho(A^2x,A^2y) < \rho(x,y)?$

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove (or disprove) that if A maps a compact metric set $(x, \rho)$ into itself and has $\rho(A^2x,A^2y) < \rho(x,y)$ then $A$ has a fixed point. 
My gut says that this is true and I think that it should follow directly from the Banach contraction principle, but I am struggling to show that $\rho(A^2x,A^2y) < \rho(x,y)$ implies $\rho(Ax,Ay) < \rho(x,y)$, which is a necessary condition to use the theorem.  It's very possible that the answer is there is no fixed point.  I'm honestly not sure

Comment: I presume you want $\rho(x,y)>0$ in order for $\rho(Ax,Ay)<\rho(x,y)$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown yeah isn't $\rho \geq 0$ by definition?

Comment: Yes, but my comment still stands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a more general statement: if $A^n$ is a contraction of a complete metric space $X$, then $A$ has a fixed point.

Proof: Let $x_0$ be the unique fixed point of $A^n$. Set $x_1 = Ax_0$. Then $A^nx_1 = A^n(Ax_0) = A(A^n x_0) = Ax_0 = x_1$; since fixed points are unique we're done. Compactness is unnecessary, all we need is a space in which Banach fixed point theorem applies.

Comment: Sorry it may be the sleep deprivation, but I really don't see how what you're showing gives us a contradiction because you're basically setting $x_1 = x_0$ so the fact that $x_1$ is a fixed point really doesn't seem surprising or meaningful?

Comment: I'm not setting $x_1=x_0$. I am proving that $A$ has a fixed point, if $A^n$ is a contraction mapping. This is what you wanted, right?

Comment: Ok its definitely the sleep deprivation.  I see.  So since $A^2$ has a fixed point by the Banach contraction principle, we can show that $A$ also has a fixed point. Thanks so much

Comment: glad to be of help!

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is compact and $A$ is continuous, there is a point $x\in X$ minimising $\rho(x,Ax)$.
But if $\rho(x,Ax)>0$ then $\rho(A^2x,A^3x)<\rho(x,Ax)$ and this gives
a contradiction.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying because minimizing $\rho(x, Ax)$ would mean getting $0$, but as per your comment we need $\rho(x,y) > 0$ so we can't have that?